# NUnit and AppDomain's UnhandledExceptionEventHandler

Tags: nunit, backgroundworker, appdomain, unhandled-exception

I'm having some issues writing a unit test in NUnit that checks that a custom exception (ProcessException) is thrown by a background worker in its RunWorkerCompleted event - for the sake of argument let's assume that we can't change that code.

What I've tried to do is to hook up to the AppDomain's UnhandledExceptionHandler in my unit test as follows:

```
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        UnhandledExceptionEventHandler handler = null;

        handler = (s, e) =>
        {
            // Need to make it clear that an exception is expected in the output window
            Console.WriteLine("==== Unhandled exception has been caught ====");
            processExceptionWasThrownByBackgroundWorker = true;
            currentDomain.UnhandledException -= handler;
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(ProcessException), e.GetType());
        };

        currentDomain.UnhandledException += handler;

        CallMyBackgroundWorkerThatThrows();

        Assert.AreEqual(true, processExceptionWasThrownByBackgroundWorker);
```

This unit test runs fine and passes when run from within visual studio using TestDriven.Net. However, when it runs on the build machine it **appears** that the NUnit console is also catching the unhandled exception [1] and returning a failure for the NUnit process, while reporting that the tests all pass. In fact, it is trying to deserialise the custom exception - ProcessException - and failing, which is what I think is being described here [2]

[1] : http://www.mail-archive.com/nunit-core@lists.launchpad.net/msg00326.html

[2] : http://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nunit-discuss/7LF_X-yBWJ8

Output from build machine:

```
[exec] Tests run: 147, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 27.6745774 seconds
[exec] Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0
[exec] Unhandled exceptions:
[exec] 1) Blah.ShelledProcessBackgroundRunnerTests.A_background_process_will_be_killed_if_the_timeout_is_exceeded : System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to find assembly 'Blah, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
[exec] at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
[exec] at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
[exec] at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
[exec] at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
[exec] at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
[exec] at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
[exec] at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
[exec] at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
[exec] at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
[exec] at System.AppDomain.Deserialize(Byte[] blob)
[exec] at System.AppDomain.UnmarshalObject(Byte[] blob)
[exec] c:\build_work\ourcibuild(229,26): External Program Failed: C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.5.10\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console-x86.exe (return code was -100)
```

Is this an accurate reflection of what is likely to be going on?
Can I change NUnit's behaviour to ignore the unhandled exception, given that I am handling it inside the unit test?

Comment: Can't you use NUnit's ExpectedExceptionAttribute or Assert.Throws<T> instead?

Comment: No, this doesn't work.

Comment: It should work though. The code you wrote will execute and then assert, most runners will stop at the exception as they do not anticipate it. The right way of testing for this is using the following:

   Assert.Throws<Exceptiontype>(() => CallMyBackgroundWorkerThatThrows());

just as Panos has suggested above. If that does not work, you need to look into why it does not work, since it is the correct way of handling exceptions in unit tests.